# Really simple encryption for epoch

Tags: shell, hash, xor

I'm writing my own list manager and I need a simple short URL for users to "one click" to unsubscribe, e.g. http://unsubscribe.example.com/50d178fa

`50d178fa` is just a hex of epoch, which is too guessable I like to think. One could be malicious and just unsubscribe people by correctly guessing the hex for a certain time period.

So I'm looking for some *light protection*. `xor` seems simplest. Any other "suck less" suggestions using a secret that generates an "unguessable string" not longer than 8 characters that I might be missing?

```
    epoch=$(date +%s)
    hex=$(printf '%x' $epoch)
    echo Convert epoch to hex
    echo d:$epoch h:$hex

    echo h:$hex is ${#hex} characters long

    echo Conversion from hex back to epoch
    echo h:$hex d:$(printf "%dn" 0x$hex)

    n=911 # secret number

    obfuscated=$(($epoch ^ $n))
    obfuscatedhex=$(printf '%x' $obfuscated)
    echo d:$obfuscated, h:$obfuscatedhex is ${#obfuscatedhex} characters long
    echo Conversion from hex back to epoch
    echo $(($(printf "%dn" 0x$obfuscatedhex) ^ $n))
```

Comment: https://github.com/kaihendry/sg-hackandtell/blob/master/README.md is opensource project where this question is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head -c 4 /dev/urandom | xxd -p
```

To expand, xor is not very good for obfuscating if you xor against the same thing every time. If someone gets a few examples of these links, they will get `a ^ n`, `b ^ n`, `c ^ n`, for `a`, `b`, and `c`, which are times (and thus, will generally only differ in the last few bits). They can calculate `(a ^ n) ^ (b ^ n)` = `(a ^ b) ^ (n ^ n)` = `(a ^ b)`, which will show them just the bits that differ between `a` and `b`. If they do the same with `c` and either of those, they'll realize that it's just the low-order bits which differ in each case. So they can take the values they have, and start guessing by flipping low-order bits. xor against a secret hasn't actually bought you any protection from someone trying to guess values; flipping a few low-order bits is just as easy for timestamps xored against a fixed value as it is against the timestamp directly.

For it to be secure, you need to use a different value every time; a one time pad, in which you use a different, secure, random number each time, or a function that can securely generate a new value from a key. In the first case, if you're using a new random number each time, why not just use that number as the key? In the second, you would need to use a stream cipher, which generates a pseudorandom stream that you could use for xoring your output from a secret key that you hold. But you would then need to keep track of where you were in that stream; if you ever repeat the stream, you run into the same old problem that you had, so this approach is much more complicated and delicate.

You already have a good, easy to use source of cryptographically secure unguessable values in `/dev/urandom`. You might as well use that. Just store the random value per subscriber; it's just 4 bytes per subscriber (or 8 if you store the hex value). Now, 32 bits is not great security; with enough tries, there's a good chance that someone could unsubscribe someone else. But if you do anything to rate-limit attempts, it shouldn't be too bad. And you can always easily increase the security by just fetching more bytes for each link.

Comment: Since I log already the epoch for a list of subscribed users, I was thinking to leverage that "id". However you are correct in the sense I could just give them random ids as you've elegantly pointed out.

Comment: @hendry Tried to reply, but it wouldn't fit in a comment, so updated my answer instead.

Comment: Thanks Brian, thats an incredible answer. The only other thought I've had since, is maybe I should just gone with an encoded version of the subscriber's email. That should not be guessable. It will be longer I guess(not sure how to encode), but hopefully it's a better, more apparent API to most.

Comment: @hendry Sure, you could use an encoded form of the email, if you encrypted it with a strong key, or you could use an [HMAC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt) or something of the sort, but that's starting to get fairly complicated. Remember; you just need a unique string that you can use to look up the subscriber record, that won't be easily guessable. Storing a random number per record and using that is about as easy as that gets.

Comment: I wouldn't have to ENCRYPT the email. Unless I'm worried that I'm exposing a user's email in the clear or something. The email itself is  a good enough secret and the malicious attacker won't know my subscribers emails, with any luck.

Comment: @hendry Email addresses are anything but secret. I don't know what your use case is, but it's pretty easy to buy a bunch of email addresses and submit unsubscribe requests for each one. With a big enough set, they will probably unsubscribe some of your users. Or someone who knows one of your users, and their email, might unsubscribe them. Using an email address plus an authenticator, such as an HMAC of the address and a secret key, would be fine; then you can't unsubscribe someone with just an email address. It depends on how secure you need to be; I like to err on the side of secure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21376/discussion-between-hendry-and-brian-campbell)